# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, office-interop, office-automation

i am getting above exception for line of code below:

```
 System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
 byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imageurl"].Value.ToString());
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
 System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
 string strImagePath = pptdirectoryPath + "\\" + currentSlide + "_" + shape.Id + ".png";
 img.Save(strImagePath);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape sp = shape;

 xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgwidth"].Value = xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgwidth"].Value.Replace("px", "");
 xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgheight"].Value = xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgheight"].Value.Replace("px", "");

 //Getting exception on below line
 shape.Fill.UserPicture(strImagePath);
```

and `strImagePath` is `D:\projects\MAMMP\trunk\Applications\Applications.Web\\cache\ppt\60ba9d41-00e0-44fd-9c2c-7591c881a1a0\\6_1026.png`

any help guys.

Comment: BTW: the Title is complete wrong... Tags also... Jes... No wonder it got downvotes...

Comment: First, your Title is not a Question, it's just the short Exception Text. Second your Tags (Powerpoint,..) haven't absolutely nothing to do with this Problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Smartis:i dont know the root of this problem.and i am not finding anything with such exception for interop. and every answer is referring to different different problem in various cases

Comment: E_FAIL is a generic unknown error. There is no more specific information.

Rather than searching for E_FAIL, I'd search for support more specific to some of the COM components you are using, specifically which one actually returned this error if you can find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix

> \\

and

> \

in the String Path.

Maybe it should look like:

```
string strImagePath = pptdirectoryPath + currentSlide + "_" + shape.Id + ".png";
```

The **pptdirectoryPath** string has also a backslash to much.

---

A single backslash is a so-called 'escape' character. This is used to include special characters like tab (\t) or a new line (\n). In order to specify a backslash in the case of a path you will have to 'espace' the single slash using the escape character, which means that you will have to write a double backslash.